# TFS 2015 Build / Release - View History Test Results for Automated Test Cases

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, tfs-2015, ms-release-management, mtm

In the old TFS 2013 days, if you wire up your automated test cases with MTM and run them via MTM, you can view all historical test results for each of those test cases in the Test Plan.

With TFS 2015 Build/Release + Run Functional Tests tasks, in MTM, you can only see the latest result. How can you view all historical runs of a particular test case? In the web portal, you can see "Test Runs", but there's no way to find just the runs pertaining to the particular test case in question.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into a workaround for this by accident. If I manually mark the test as Pass/Fail, then when I go back to MTM, and "View Results" again for this test case, it will all of a sudden display everything in its history, including the automated test runs generated by builds or releases.

It seems like a bug in the MTM UI, but this works for now!

[image: All history is now displayed after a manual pass/fail]